# Convolutional Layers for non-image data

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, data-representation

I often see guides and examples using Convolutional Layers when implementing Deep Q-Networks. This makes sense for some scenarios, typically where you do not have access to the state in for example an array representation.

In my case, I have a game environment which gives me complete access to the state, in form of a 2D array. This 2D array is later interpreted by a graphics engine and dawn to the screen.
I have been recommended to use Convolutional Layers for interpreting images, but I have yet to see any recommendations about flattening the 2D State representation directly and utilize dense layers instead.

Does it make any sense to use Convolutional Networks/Layers for data which are not an image?

Comment: why is this data stored as 2D object? Is there a spatial correlation? Meaning that neighbouring "memory cells" represent correlated things? Or this 2D representation is arbitrary?

Comment: This 2D representation is just a convenient way of storing the state information for the game. The game itself is much like a chess board. Where there are 2 layers of information, Player identification and "Unit" Type. In my case, the layout of this is an  [11x30 grid with following layers](http://i.imgur.com/Xf6PHQx.png).

So far I've tried to model my network for using heat maps, pixel-input, and raw state. So far raw-state, where I flatten directly and have 3 dense layers, performs the best.